# No sound output of any kind from lenovo X1 Carbon running ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.04, alsa, lenovo

I'm fairly new to ubuntu and linux in general so bear with me but I can't make the built in sound card (Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio) work. When I open sound settings I get dummy output and opening the dropdown menu shows no other options. In HDAJackretask it shows "No codecs found. Sorry" in the top left and when i try to open alsamixer through terminal it shows "cannot find card "0"". When i had alsamixer working yesterday it had me select between 5 different s/pdif options but wouldn't let me change volume across them or show a headphone/speaker output of any kind. I've tried to work through this using various forums and i've done the generic turn everything off and on again, reinstall alsa and pulseaudio but i'm at a complete loss